# Spring Boot: Best way to return 503 HttpStatus in ResponseEntity if the DataSource is DOWN

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using `Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE` & i have a REST api, exposing several endpoints. If the DB is down, i would like to return a **503** to the caller.

I could use the `DataSourceHealthIndicator` provided for free by `Spring Boot` if the `DataSource` is configured etc like so:

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Status;

@Autowired 
private DataSourceHealthIndicator d;

@PostMapping(value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<jsonResponse> someMethod()(
    @PathVariable String id, 
    @Valid @RequestBody SomeDto someDto) {

  //some code

  if(Status.DOWN.getCode().equals(d.getHealth(false).getStatus().getCode())) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonResponse, HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
  }
```

Is there a better way to do it as i believe it is hitting the DB everytime the end-point is being called and therefore probably an **expensive** way of doing.

Comment: How else would you know if your database is down without actually checking it?

Comment: Hi @KrisztianToth, we need to check it, but i am looking for an "efficient" way to check it. Checking it everytime an endpoint is being accessed is **expensive**, i am looking for a **cheaper** alternative. I guess i am not the only one facing this "issue" and a *better solution* is probably already out there ^^.

Comment: You can configure the health check endpoint to do a different lightweight query than the default (I think it defaults to something like `select 1`), but you're going to have to talk to the DB to know if it's down, that's not going to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rely on a Spring Boot solution then I would suggest Spring Cache https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/

Add the Maven dependency `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>`, enable caching in the SpringBoot Application class with `@EnableCaching`, then define which methods should cache the result.
This method will hit the DB only during the first call, all others invocation relies on the cached value.

```
@Cacheable("records")
public Record getByName(String name) {
  return getRecordRepository().findByName(name);
}
```

If using the Spring native (in-memory) cache you need to evict the objects at some point to ensure you don't hold stale data (unless it is a readOnly object that never changes, not a very common use case probably).

In your scenario (if I understand correctly) you could have a thread then every x seconds check the DB, and if healthy you can evict the cache with a dedicated method:

```
@CacheEvict(allEntries = true, cacheNames = { "records"})
public void evictAllRecords() {
   // evict all records every 10 minutes
}
```

Comment: Hey @BeppeC, i ended up not using caching as the DataSourceHealthIndicator is fetching the result in ms, which is good enough for me. I accepted your answer, because after much looking around and trying, your solution would be the way to go if caching is needed, probably with Caffeine as the cache library.

Comment: @jumping_monkey hi, thanks for confirming the approach, DataSourceHealthIndicator seems indeed a good approach

Answer (score 0):

if you expected a high number of requests you can consider a separate thread (DB health status) which pings the DB every X seconds. In this way the incoming HTTP requests do not need to hit the DB if you know it is unavailable.

If your volume is not large however it is probably best to attempt the connection and deal with the unavailable DB situation, in this way you do need the extra thread and the requests resume working as soon as the DB is again reachable (while with the thread you might have a slight delay depending on the interval you configure).

Comment: Hi @BeppeC, your comments is more or less what i am *looking for*, but in terms of a Spring Boot solution that someone has already implemented perhaps?An "@Annotation"? Calling the DB every time an endpoint is being hit, is **expensive**. Therefore, i am looking for something like to "cache" the "DB result" and access the "cache" to check if the DB is up. The "DB result" will be updated like ever "X seconds".

Answer (score 0):

The DataSource will typically validate the connections for you and throw an exception if it cannot get a connection, so you could create a [custom error handler](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) for the specific exception type that is thrown and use that to return a custom response entity with 503.

Only caveat is that the exception is `SQLException`, which could be any number of issues not related to connection. Your error handler would need to be smart enough to understand which error codes in `SQLException` really mean unavailable.